# Sort NSMutableDictionary in ASC order

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

In my Xcode Project (Objective-C), i store json Result in a NSMutableDictionary, but the result is in false order direction.

How can i sort a `NSMutableDictionary` is ASC order on Objective-C.

Here is my `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
{
    3 =     (
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20
    );
    2 =     (
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
    );
    1 =     (
        0,
        1
    );
    4 =     (
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26
    );
}
```

I expect a sort order 1,2,3,4 for `UITableView` Section.

Comment: Dictionaries have no order. You would need to create an array from the keys and then sort that array.

Answer (score 0):

@rmaddy is right,the following is the implementation code, very simple.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)sortDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary {
    NSArray *sortedKeys = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sortedKeys.count];
    for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
        [sortedArray addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]];
    }
    return sortedArray;
}
```

example

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"3":@{@"3333":@"3333"},
                       @"2":@{@"2222":@"2222"},
                       @"1":@{@"1111":@"1111"},
                       @"4":@{@"4444":@"444"}};

[self sortDictionary:dict];
```

result:

```
sortedArray :(
        {
        1111 = 1111;
    },
        {
        2222 = 2222;
    },
        {
        3333 = 3333;
    },
        {
        4444 = 444;
    }
)
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue. Even if you sort the key and store them in "order", order in the print it no guaranteed. Nor the access.

Comment: Thank you, I think I was just confused, the dictionary is unordered.